# Unity + GoogleVR: How to disable stereoscopy?

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-cardboard, google-vr, virtual-reality

I'm making a (2D) 360 image viewer in Unity for GoogleVR/Cardboard, and each eye is receiving a slightly different view of the scene for a stereoscopic effect. I'd like to disable this, and have each eye receive the same image.

Comment: In the Unity Hierarchy, you'll see GvrMain (or similar) under Head/Main Camera you'll see that there are two separate cameras, one feeding each eye.  These cameras are offset from each other by a distance which matches the distance between the lenses in your Google Cardboard viewer.  To make them render the same view you need to put them together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why you would like to disable this but assuming you're using GoogleVR assets, you can set the values of **Eye** property of `GvrEye` scripts to *Center* (they are found on *Main Camera Left* and *Main Camera Right* game objects at runtime), then you set the **transform.position.x** to *0* and the **transform.localEulerAngles.y** to respectively *-8* and *+8* on *Main Camera Left* and *Main Camera Right* (those values seem good to me but you can tweak them I guess).

Answer (score 0):

public class GvrView
A View that supports VR rendering.

Designed to work in full screen mode with a landscape or reverse landscape orientation.

This view can be used like a GLSurfaceView by implementing one of its rendering interfaces:

GvrView.StereoRenderer: abstracts all stereoscopic rendering details from the renderer.
GvrView.Renderer: for complex engines that need to handle all stereo rendering details by themselves.
The GvrView.StereoRenderer interface is recommended for all applications that can make use of it, while the GvrView.Renderer interface is discouraged and should only be used if really needed.

The view allows switching from stereo mode to mono rendering mode in stereo renderers at any time by calling the setStereoModeEnabled method.

More info please read
https://developers.google.com/vr/android/reference/com/google/vr/sdk/base/GvrView

Comment: Thanks for the info but this only applies for the non-unity gvr